# Is $query->get_result() the Correct Way to Get Results?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I currently have the following code;

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers';
$query = $con->prepare( $sql );
$query->execute();
$rr = $query->get_result();


while ($s = $rr->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $s['name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $s['email'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $s['mobile'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Is this the correct way to get results from the database using mysqli?

Comment: is that the correct way? yes should work if you have `mysqlnd` installed in your env. why not try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a perfectly acceptable way of getting the results from a prepared statement, but it will only work if you have the native mysqli extension installed (if you have the native PHP installation, then it should be present). You could also use `$query->bind_result()` and fill variables directly, like this;

```
$sql = 'SELECT name,email,mobile FROM customers';
$query = $con->prepare( $sql );
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($name, $email, $mobile);

while ($query->fetch()) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $name . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $email . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $mobile . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Note the variables are filled (in the order they are retrieved from the database, hence why I explicitly named the columns in my example) with the data for the next line each time `$query->fetch()` is called, so you need the `while` loop to go through all the data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @worldofjr thanks this is perfect i think. i just started learning this. thanks again

Comment: @john No problem. If this or any other answer solves your question, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the tick-mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: @worldofjr one more thing, after this executing do i need to close the stmt like $query->close() and then closing the connecting $con->close().

Comment: @john You don't **need** to close the query or the connection. There is very little gain by doing so, but if you aren't going to use query/connection again then there's no harm either.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

//First make a connection to the database server:
$mysql = new mysqli("host_or_ip", "username", "password", "database");

//Then check your new connection
if($mysql->connect_errno){
    die("DB connection failed: ", $mysql->connect_error);
}

//Run a select query and check there are no errors
$result = $mysql->query("SELECT book_name FROM bookshelf LIMIT 30");
if(!result){
    die("Error running query: ".$result->error);
}

//Output the results
echo("".
    "<table>".
        "<thead>".
            "<tr>".
                "<th>Book Name</th>".
                "<th>Author</th>".
                "<th>Publisher</th>".
            "</tr>".
        "</thead>".
        "<tbody>");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['book_name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['author'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['publisher'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo("</tbody></table>");
```

Answer (score -1):

I dnt know if you did a conenction to db .
Please check this example too:

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbDatabase);
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('select * from foobar');
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();

    while ($column = $meta->fetch_field()) {
       $bindVarsArray[] = &$results[$column->name];
    }       
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $bindVarsArray);

    $stmt->fetch();

    echo var_dump($results);
    // outputs:
    //
    // array(3) {
    //  ["id"]=>
    //  &int(1)
    //  ["foo"]=>
    //  &string(11) "This is Foo"
    //  ["bar"]=>
    //  &string(11) "This is Bar"
    // }
    ?>
```

Comment: Yuck! That is messy, and there's plenty of lines that make no sense at all, such as the use of `$stmt->fetch()` on it's own.

Comment: It's a very poor example.